# 400.0 Bad Request on REST API on Azure Web Site

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have migrated a REST service to an Azure web site, but it keeps coming back with a `400.0 Bad Request` error (error code zero).

The service works locally, and works perfectly when running in a Web Role.  After moving into a Web Site, it started coming back with the 400.0 error.

My web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I already have ASP.NET compatibility set in my class:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class BookingService { ... }
```

and the proper routing defined in Global.asax.cs:

```
private void Application_Start (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("booking/service", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(BookingService)));
}
```

Now when I try to access the REST API locally, it works fine:

```
http://localhost/booking/service/help
```

However, after uploading the web service into an Azure Web Site and doing:

```
http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/booking/service/help
```

it came back with a 400.0 Bad Request.  Detailed error logs show:

```
Request: ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler:  System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler
Error code: 0x00000000
```

I am at a total lost.  Googling the web didn't yield anything helpful.  I tried putting the following into web.config:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="Foo.RoutingHandler" />
</handlers>
```

and defining a handler by extending `UrlRoutingHandler` and defining `VerifyAndProcessRequest` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the error after stripping the service off bit by bit.

What happened was:

- `RouteTable.Routes.Add` adds a route that creates an object of class `BookingService` as the handler
- The class `BookingService` has a *static* property that is initialized
- This initialization statement failed (due to some reason not to mention here)
- Therefore, when the routing service tries to create a `BookingService` class, the class's static initializers were first run and failed
- As a result, the code never reached the routing service, and so the service failed at the AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler handler
- If the class failed not while running static initializers, but during object creation, it is likely that the routing service will then throw a more meaningful error pin-pointing the problem

In summary, if you see a routed request failing at the handler, it may be caused by class code that couldn't load (due to static initializers failing or some other reason).